# How to create a hyperlink to a file in an array (paginated files)

Tags: php, html, dynamic, hyperlink, pagination

I've been playing around with pagination using arrays in php. 
I have an array of posts that I use to break the content of a page up into smaller chunks. It works and returns the content as I would like.

```
<?php
// let's paginate data from an array...
$posts = array(
// array of posts

"blog/posts/06-19-tues.php",
"blog/posts/06-16-sat.php",

"blog/posts/05-26-sat.php",
"blog/posts/05-23-wed.php",
"blog/posts/05-09-wed.php"

);

// how many records should be displayed on a page?
$records_per_page = 3;

// include the pagination class
require 'zebra/Zebra_Pagination.php';

// instantiate the pagination object
$pagination = new Zebra_Pagination();

// the number of total records is the number of records in the array
$pagination->records(count($posts));

// records per page
$pagination->records_per_page($records_per_page);

// here's the magick: we need to display *only* the records for the current page
$posts = array_slice(
    $posts,
    (($pagination->get_page() - 1) * $records_per_page),
    $records_per_page
);

?>

<?php foreach ($posts as $index => $post):?>
<?php include $post; ?>
<?php endforeach?>

<?php

// render the pagination links
$pagination->render();

?>
```

My question is now how to link to the individual posts from elsewhere on the site. Since they will, ultimately move from page to page, linking directly to the static file won't work. At first, I had given each post a unique id and used that to link to the post but that won't work now since the link will change, dynamically.

I've looked at array_search() and it looks promising but I don't understand it's use enough to get it to produce a hyperlink.

I'm not sure I've phrased this question all that well. apologies if I don't make much sense.

Comment: Do you mean a link to a specific page within the pagination?

Comment: No, not to a specific page but a specific file, let's say an image, for example. 

On the first page, I could link to it by pointing directly to the file. That would work for a while until it moves to page 2 because there's more content.

Comment: If you're not linking to the pagination, why does the page number matter when linking directly to the target file?

Comment: I want to be able to link to the file within the context of the main page and directly to the file, itself.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I think something like this will work:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['page']) {
  $found = array_search($_REQUEST['page'], $posts);
  if ($found) {
    $pagination->set_page(floor($found/$records_per_page)+1);
  }
}
```

Then you can use a link like

```
$link = '<a href="yourpage.php?page=' . urlencode($posts[$i]) . '">whatever</a>';
```

Comment: Thank you. I haven't had a chance to try it yet but it does look like what I need.